# Why do the engines of the PAK FA (Sukhoi T-50) seem not to be not aligned parallel to each other?

Tags: aircraft-design, fighter, russia, sukhoi-pak-fa

The nozzles of the Sukhoi T-50 seem to be aligned not perfectly parallel. However, it is not very pronounced.

What may be the reasons for aligning the <s>nozzles</s> engines not perfectly parallel.

**Edit:** in my original post I asked about the nozzles, however, as it was pointed out, this plane used 3D thrust vectoring, so the nozzle arrangement might be this way by chance. However, also the engines seem to be aligned not perfectly parallel. The question has been edited accordingly.

[image: Suchoi T-50]
[Image source Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:T-50-2_%28aircraft%29#/media/File:Sukhoi_T-50_at_the_MAKS-2013_%2801%29.jpg)

**Edit 2:** Here is another picture [image: of a PAK-FA with a Mig-29]
[Image source, Wikipedia again](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sukhoi_T-50_in_2012_%285%29.jpg)

Comment: Might be the thrust vectoring being used.

Comment: You might clarify if you're actually talking about the nozzles, in which case Adder's answer applies. But looking at aircraft photos I think you are probably asking about why the entire engines are skewed slightly apart.

Comment: Good point about the engines. Initially it was the alignment of the engines that triggered this question. However, it got formulated to be about the nozzles, which is not the same for 3D thrust vectoring aircraft.

Comment: Regarding your edit, this might just be the paint job playing tricks on you.

Comment: @sanchises: I am not sure if it is solely an illusion. Compared with other planes, e.g. the Mig-29 the engines of the Pak-FA seem not quite parallel.

Comment: Might just be an optical illusion. There is no "good" reason for them not to be parallel that I can think of. If they really are not parallel, but sort of v-shaped, then someone goofed during the design process.

Comment: In the picture above, is the MiGs left nozzle open and the right one closed?

Comment: Are you sure about the 3D vectoring capability? That would mean the nozzles can pitch, yaw, and roll the aircraft.

Answer (score 5):

The Sukhoi T-50 operates Thrust vectoring nozzle control at low speeds. The nozzles are a part of the Fly By Wire system and will deflect as per the control input given by the pilot. The nozzles move in coordination with other flight controls and it is not necessary for them to be parallel in all conditions of flight. However on the ground they will appear to be parallel.

Comment: To add to this, it's actually a condition of the PAK-FA nozzles that they're not parallel. Otherwise they wouldn't be able to perform 3D thrust vectoring (as they'd lack moment in 2 of the axes).

Comment: Depends on the degrees of freedom the nozzles have to move. There are different types of vectoring nozzles.